# How to display only telephone number field in customer registration page

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account

how to add only telephone field from address fields in registration page of magento.

I have found way to enable address fields. But i need only telephone number field alone from address fields in registration.

Please suggest a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Go With the following path :

```
\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\persistent\customer\form\register.phtml
```

and comment the if condition from here. :

```
<?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
```

otherwise get the telephone field outside the if condition.

Happy Codding. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add below layout in any layout xml file:

```
<customer_account_create>
  <reference name="customer_form_register">
     <action method="setShowAddressFields"><param>true</param></action>
  </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

**Note:** Please don't change in core files. Just make a copy of the layout file in theme directory & add above code.

Comment: But It's adding all the address fields to my registration page. I want only telephone number field from address section.