# Add telephone filed in register page

Tags: magento-1.9, register

I want to get just telephone filed in my customer register page

```
 <?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
```

I use above code But It's adding all the address fields to my registration page. I want only telephone number field from address section.

Answer (score 1):

Add Telephone to customer registration,customer edit page etc. run following setup script from magento root.

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php'); 
umask(0);
Mage::app();


$installer = new Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$installer->startSetup();

$vCustomerEntityType = $installer->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$vCustAttributeSetId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($vCustomerEntityType);
$vCustAttributeGroupId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($vCustomerEntityType, $vCustAttributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'cust_telephone', array(
        'label' => 'Customer Telephone',
        'input' => 'text',
        'type'  => 'varchar',
        'forms' => array('customer_account_edit','customer_account_create','adminhtml_customer','checkout_register'),
        'required' => 0,
        'user_defined' => 1,
));

$installer->addAttributeToGroup($vCustomerEntityType, $vCustAttributeSetId, $vCustAttributeGroupId, 'mobile', 0);

$oAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'cust_telephone');
$oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_account_edit','customer_account_create','adminhtml_customer','checkout_register'));
$oAttribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

Run this Script, it will add attribute "cust_telephone" and now you can use this attribute in the register form, like this

```
<li class="fields">
    <div class="field">
        <label><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Customer Telephone') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="cust_telephone" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getCust_Telephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Customer Telephone') ?>" class="input-text" />
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

the code is tested, will work 100% ;)

[image: Backend]

[image: Frontend]

Comment: thanks but i need to add data(number) to telephone field not create new field in magento database tables- its make problem to my extensions

Comment: without address i don't think telephone number get save

Comment: this code created a new field.. tested in magento 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Go With the following path :

```
\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\persistent\customer\form\register.phtml
```

Get the telephone field outside the if condition. If you want to show only telephone field.

```
<?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
```

Comment: when i use this code it show all address fields, i need just telephone field to show and save telephone correctly

Comment: [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111209/how-to-display-only-telephone-number-field-in-customer-registration-page) will helps you. remove above xml from your file and get the telephone field outside the if condition. from **\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\persistent\customer\form\register.phtml**  check here https://prnt.sc/ikfrbt

Comment: tnks for answer but telephone number that i insert in register page doesnt save  in database and show null!

Comment: did you got solution ?

Comment: when i move telephone filed befor if condition it doesnt save telephone in database- and if i use telephone filed in if condion and delete other fields it gave validation errors for (state,city, etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the telephone number field and exclude all other address related fields, then the easy way would be add below code in `register.phtml` file wherever you need.

File: `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/customer/form/register.phtml`

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="telephone" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Telephone')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This would be the easy choice in this case.